# Deserialize Json object using Jackson library with Joda Datetime

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, jackson

I'm trying to use the Jackson library to deserialize a Json object and i'm having some trouble in the Joda Datetime format deserialization.

This code throws the following error:

Unable to resolve Lorg/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant; annotation class 1557

```
DataWrapper list = mapper.readValue(response, DataWrapper.class);
```

I already try to find something about this but nothing.

There is the complete code:

```
public class DataWrapper {
    public List<ScheduleEntry> data;
}

public static class ScheduleEntry {
    public long ID;
public DateTime StartDate;
public DateTime EndDate;
public String Description;
}

WebService callWebService = new WebService(SERVICE_URI);        
String response = callWebService.webInvoke("/GetScheduleEntrys", params);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

try
{    
    DataWrapper list = mapper.readValue(response, DataWrapper.class);

    List<ScheduleEntry> items = list.data;
}
```

WebService:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
   UriTemplate = "GetScheduleEntrys",
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<ScheduleEntry> GetScheduleEntrys(string Token);
```

JSON:

[{"Description":"Cliente José","EndDate":"/Date(1353319200000+0000)/","ID":0,"StartDate":"/Date(1353315600000+0000)/"},{"Description":"Cliente Carlos","EndDate":"/Date(1353348000000+0000)/","ID":0,"StartDate":"/Date(1353344400000+0000)/"},{"Description":"Cliente Pedro","EndDate":"/Date(1353513600000+0000)/","ID":0,"StartDate":"/Date(1353510000000+0000)/"},{"Description":"Cliente Marco","EndDate":"/Date(1353664800000+0000)/","ID":0,"StartDate":"/Date(1353661200000+0000)/"},{"Description":"Cliente José","EndDate":"/Date(1353319200000+0000)/","ID":0,"StartDate":"/Date(1353315600000+0000)/"},{"Description":"Cliente Carlos","EndDate":"/Date(1353348000000+0000)/","ID":0,"StartDate":"/Date(1353344400000+0000)/"},{"Description":"Cliente Pedro","EndDate":"/Date(1353513600000+0000)/","ID":0,"StartDate":"/Date(1353510000000+0000)/"},{"Description":"Cliente Marco","EndDate":"/Date(1353664800000+0000)/","ID":0,"StartDate":"/Date(1353661200000+0000)/"}]

Full log

01-03 17:39:24.700: E/dalvikvm(18494): Unable to resolve Lorg/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant; annotation class 1557
01-03 17:39:28.505: W/dalvikvm(18494): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c4d1f8)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/convert/ToString
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Native Method)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:267)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._addMixUnders(AnnotatedClass.java:999)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._addMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:610)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveMemberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:421)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.memberMethods(AnnotatedClass.java:243)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addMethods(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:442)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collect(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:232)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(BasicClassIntrospector.java:142)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:81)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:11)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig.introspect(DeserializationConfig.java:507)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:326)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:143)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:325)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:633)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:427)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:295)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:143)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:325)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:147)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:23)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:329)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:633)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:427)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:295)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
01-03 17:39:28.650: E/AndroidRuntime(18494):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(Deserialize

Comment: Add the full stacktrace please, and the JSON you are retrieving from the web service.

Comment: There it is, can you suggest something now?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Exception would indicate that you are using incompatible Joda version (most likely an older version).

But looking at JSON, your date values are being serialized using some non-standard notation, so you will probably need to write custom handlers as well (or change serialization format).

Comment: I already try other versions os Joda and it throws the same exception. What is the most common way to change the serialization format? By my search it's recommended to change the Datetime format to String in the webservice, is that a good solution? Thanks for your reply by the way

Comment: Jackson has configuration options for date/time handling, both global (via `ObjectMapper` or `ObjectWriter`), and annotation-based (`@JsonFormat`, JAckson 2.0 and above).

Answer (score 0):

Given the JSON you have,
you need to have this statement in your mapper.
`DataWrapper.setData(mapper.readValue(response, new TypeReference<List<ScheduleEntry>>()
            {
            }));`

This will not resolve the original issue that you are facing:
`Unable to resolve Lorg/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant; annotation class 1557`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How the method .setData looks like?

Comment: You already have this `public class DataWrapper {
    public List<ScheduleEntry> data; // or if you prefer, setters+getters
}`. Just create a setter called `public void setData(List<ScheduleEntry> inputData) {data=inputData;}`